# Unitarily similarity

Tags: matrices

I don't know how to show that $A\in M_2$ is unitarily similar to $\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&x\\0&\lambda_2\end{bmatrix}$, where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ is its eigenvalues, $x^2=\text{tr}AA^*-|\lambda_1|^2-|\lambda_2|^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Note that if $A=U MU^\ast$ (where $M$ is the matrix you wrote) then

$$AA^\ast=(UMU^\ast)(UMU^\ast)^\ast=UMU^\ast U M^\ast U^\ast=UMM^\ast U^\ast$$

So,

$$\text{tr}(AA^\ast)=\text{tr}(UMM^\ast U^\ast)=\text{tr}(MM^\ast)$$

Now, what is $\text{tr}(MM^\ast)$?

Comment: More hints here are helpful, I do know that if $A$ is unitarily similar to $M$, then $$\text{tr}AA^*=\text{tr}MM^*.$$But this doesn't guarantee that $A$ is unitarily similar to $M$

Comment: @user95640 No more hints are helpful. Compute $\text{tr}(MM^\ast)$ and then stare at it..

Comment: $\text{tr}MM^*=|\lambda_1|^2+|\lambda_2|^2+x^2$, since $x^2=\text{tr}AA^*-|\lambda_1|^2-|\lambda_2|^2$, we have $\text{tr}MM^*=\text{tr}AA^*$, right? And then....

Comment: I'm wondering whether I should figure out what $U$ is.

Comment: Oh, I see, Specht's theorem right? $\text{tr}W(A,A^*)=\text{tr}W(B,B^*)$

Comment: @user95640 I must be misunderstanding your question. I thought the problem was to show that if $A$ is unitarily similar to $\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1 & x\\ 0 & \lambda_2\end{pmatrix}$ then the Frobenius norm of $A$ is $|x|^2+|\lambda_1|^2+|\lambda_2|^2$. Was it not?